# Who actually installs the Java MIDlet file

Tags: java, java-me, midlet, sis

Suppose i have TicTacToe.jar (Collection of class files and resource files) & TicTacToe.jad (Descriptor File) files,

Who and How does this installation from jar file to some machine dependant files like (.sis and all)

Platform independant                               Platform Dependant
JAR File <----------------> (???????) <----------> .sis Files

Answer (score 1):

Although your question is not 100% clear I will try to answer the question as I understood it.

First JME is supported by several platforms while sys files belong to Symbian only. 
Second, JME application distribution really consists of 2 files: JAR and JAD. The installation starts from JAD. Java installer (built in into the platform) detects JAD, reads its data, asks user to confirm his/her wish to really install the application and then downloads JAR file and "installs" it.

The process may start from HTTP request (so called OTA - over the air installation), from memory card, from bluetooth. Bottom line: the java installer takes responsibility to install the midlet.